# "[:,]" list slicing python, what does it mean?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm reading some code and I see `" list[:,i] for i in range(0,list))......"`

I am mystified as to what comma is doing in there, `:,` and google offers no answers as you cant google punctuation.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Googling `list slicing python comma` works. Just mentioning it because you mentioned the difficulties of searching for this.

Comment: This is a weird example, if the variable `list` is a multidimensional numpy array (as Martijn suggests) the last bit `for i in range(0,list)` doesn't make sense. Also having a variable called `list` is bad because it hides the Python `list` function...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are looking at [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/) multidimensional array slicing.

The comma marks a tuple, read it as `[(:, i)]`, which `numpy` arrays interpret as: first dimension to be sliced end-to-end (all rows) with `:`, then for each row, `i` selects *one* column.

See [Indexing, Slicing and Iterating](https://web.archive.org/web/20150802020005/http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-864862d3f2bb4c32f04260fac61eb4ef34788c4c) in the `numpy` tutorial.

Comment: Seems a weird way of doing... `for column in list.T`

Comment: @JonClements: Assuming the array is two-dimensional.  Otherwise, you need `numpy.swapaxes()` to swap the second and first axis.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Right; my newbness with numpy is shining through here.

Comment: @SvenMarnach yes - sorry - I have a bad habit of assuming that arrays are 2D... (and we know what 'assume' does...) :)

Answer (score 2):

Not trying to poach Martijn's answer, but I was puzzled by this also so wrote myself a little getitem explorer that shows what's going on. Python gives a slice object to **getitem** that objects can decide what to do with. Multidimensional arrays are tuples too.

```
>>> class X(object):
...     def __getitem__(self, name):
...             print type(name),name
...
>>> x=X()
>>> x[:,2]
<type 'tuple'> (slice(None, None, None), 2)
>>> x[1,2,3,4]
<type 'tuple'> (1, 2, 3, 4)
>>>
```

Comment: +1, this shows that objects other than numpy array's can be indexed with a tuple (note that the OP did not include the numpy tag). Still this `x` results in an error with `for i in range(0,x)`. OP should post some more of the code he/she was reading...